# Subtracting elements from dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have two dictionaries, let's say:

```
dict_a = {"A": 3.0, "C": 4.0, "B": 6.0}
dict_b = {"A": 3.0, "C": 5.0, "D": 1.0}
```

and I want to calculate a subtraction `dict_a - dict_b` so the output gives me:

```
{"A": 0.0, "B": 6.0, "C": -1.0, "D": -1.0}
```

Googling for some time I have seen people using Counter to perform operations like this, but doing something simple like

```
dict(Counter(dict_a) - Counter(dict_b))
```

only gives me

```
{"A": 0.0, "B": 6.0}
```

i.e., if the key is not in `dict_a`, it won't appear in the output.

So far, I have managed the following solution:

```
dict_b2 = dict_b.copy()
dict_c = {}
for i in dict_a.keys():
   dict_c.update({i: dict_a[i] - dict_b2.pop(i,0.0)})
   # Changes sign to the remaining values from dict_b2
dict_c.update({k: 0.0 - v for k, v in dict_b2.iteritems()})
```

but I know there has to be a much more elegant and efficient way of doing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The keys 'C' and 'D' are dropped because Counter will drop keys with negative counts.

Comment: @mgilson Sorry I forgot to mention that it happens only during the subtraction operation.

Comment: @200OK -- Yeah, I just noticed that when I looked at the docs more.  It's a good thing that it has a `.subtract` method!  :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that `Counter` has a (not very well documented) [`subtract`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l536) method:

```
>>> dict_a = {"A": 3.0, "C": 4.0, "B": 6.0}
>>> dict_b = {"A": 3.0, "C": 5.0, "D": 1.0}
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = Counter(dict_a)
>>> a.subtract(dict_b)
>>> a
Counter({'B': 6.0, 'A': 0.0, 'C': -1.0, 'D': -1.0})
```

Note that this doesn't suffer from the "no values below 0" constraint which is imposed on `Counter.__sub__`, but it does do the operation *in-place*.

One thing that is a little cool is that I didn't have to convert *both* dicts to a Counter -- only the one on the left side of the operation.

Comment: @200OK -- Me neither.  The behavior of `__sub__` just seemed really strange if this behavior didn't exist somewhere else so I went spelunking.

Comment: Oh, I should have seen that before... That's perfect! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a *dict comprehension*:

```
new_dict = {k:dict_a.get(k, 0) - dict_b.get(k, 0) 
            for k in set(dict_a).union(set(dict_b))}

# {'A': 0.0, 'C': -1.0, 'B': 6.0, 'D': -1.0}
```

Here we are using `dict#get(key, default)` to avoid getting a `KeyError` (when the key doesn't belong to one of the dictionaries).

Comment: That solution is very good too, thanks! But this time I will use the subtract method :)